# Запуск Python скрипта через supervisor

Tags: python, supervisord

Нужно запустить скрипт питона через supervisor, при команде:

`sudo supervisorctl start all`

выходит ошибка:

```
worker: ERROR (spawn error)
```

Вот конфиг:

```
[program:worker]
command=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/cdn/cgi-bin/hello.py
stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=designer
stopsignal=KILL
numprocs=1
```

Пути вроде правильные, при добавление конфига обновил супервизор...

Comment: А если посмотреть что об этого говорит supervisor в своём логе? Может там чуть больше инфы будет?

Comment: @nobody Неа, он пуст. первый раз его запускаю, даже запуститься не может, до логов так не дойти

Comment: Вы сейчас о каком логе говорите?

Comment: Запускать cgi-скрипт супервизором? Оригинально!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну так подскажите как лучше, первый раз с такой проблемой вообще столкнулся

Comment: Стоит прочитать про то, что такое CGI. Вопрос сразу отпадёт.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev уже читал. А как тогда запустить этот скрипт на фоне? Или лучше вообще не юзать CGI?

Comment: Как-то странно вы читали. Common Gateway Interface предельно примитивен, даже не представляю, как он может остаться непонятен. Запускать CGI-скрипты должен web-сервер. На каждый принятый http-запрос сервер запускает скрипт, получает его вывод, и отправляет в качестве http-ответа. CGI-скрипты по определению не могут работать "в фоне".

Comment: И да, этот интерфейс устарел уже лет десять как, если не больше. С Python лучше использовать WSGI.

Comment: **@設 計** Запустите вручную `/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/cdn/cgi-bin/hello.py` из-под пользователя `designer` и посмотрите, что получится. **@SergeyGornostaev**, а с чего Вы решили, что это CGI скрипт? Что он в папке `cgi-bin`? И с чего Вы решили, что кому-то не придет в голову сделать CGI скрипт двойного назначения - и CGI, и не CGI? Вы бы по теме бы лучше высказались, а то целая простыня offtopic сообщений...